# Cycle containing two given nodes in an undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given an undirected graph G=(V,E) and two nodes `s, t`, how to find an arbitrary SIMPLE cycle (each node used only once) containing `s` and `t`? Or just DETECT whether there is a cycle between them? Here graph G is a simple graph having no self-ring and existing at most one edge between two nodes. 
I find it easy to detect whether there is cycle in the graph, but I've no idea of detecting (or finding) a cycle containing two given nodes. I find the same problem providing some answers http://infoweekly.blogspot.fr/2009/04/puzzle-cycle-containing-two-nodes.html, but I do not understand the 'one-line answer' because it's too brief for an outsider as me.

Answer (score 1):

The one-line answer is as follows:
Suppose you want to have a '[flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network)' of $2$ through the graph, where every node has capacity $1$. If such a flow exist, there is a cycle that contains $s$ and $t$, because you can take the route of the first unit flow from $s$ to $t$ and take the route of the second unit flow back.

**EDIT**
Finding two such flows can be done using a Depth first search. That is, you just start searching (in a systematic way) for a first path from $s$ to $t$. If you found one, start searching for another (path or edge) disjunct path. If no such path exist, look for another first path. Continue until you found two disjunct paths.

I don't know if there is a more sophisticated method to do this.

Comment: Yes I got to understand what you mean. But how can I determine whether such flow exists? Any related algorithms? Thanks!

Comment: Yes I got what you mean. But the worst situation leads to finding all the paths between s and t. What if I just want to DETECT whether there exists such cycle, instead of FIND it out? Do you think the other comments provide some clue? http://infoweekly.blogspot.fr/2009/04/puzzle-cycle-containing-two-nodes.html

Answer (score 1):

I've already find a solution to check whether two nodes s and t are contained in a cycle. Suppose s and t are in a connected graph G, the procedure is:

step 1. Remove all the 'leaves' from the graph literately, so that there is at least one cycle in each component left. (refer to algorithm to detect whether there is cycle in graph)

step 2. Check whether s and t are in two different cycles but connected by a 'bridge' node. To check whether a node is a 'bridge', simply cut all the edges of it. If the resulting graph is still connected, then it's not a 'bridge', otherwise it's a bridge.

step 3. Cut the graph at the bridge nodes to distinct connected components, assign the bridge node to each components. If s and t are in different components, they are not in the same cycle, stop. Otherwise do steps 1-3 literately until no bridge nodes are found.